# Getting an IServiceProvider from Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, discord.net

I'm currently working at a discord bot and the CommandHandler needs an IServiceProvider for the Dependency Injection but I do use Ninject does anyone know a way to retrieve a ServiceProvider from Ninject? So that my binded Modules are inside the ServiceProvider?

Couldn't figure it out myself.

I would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `StandardKernel` implicitly implemented `IServiceProvider` interface.

Answer (score 0):

As corollary of what @Scott said, the interface `IKernel` extends `IServiceProvider`, so in your `RegisterServices` method, you could add a binding like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IServiceProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel);
```